# There is another way do Copy and Paste in VBS or BAT?

Tags: vbscript

I was trying to automatize some repeated fill forms that I do in my job. I automate a lot of in VBA Excel, and I wanted to do with VBS too, but the company's  computer doesn't work `"^{C}"`, eather `"%{TAB}"`.

In resume, `ALT +` or `CTRL+` doesn't has the common response and a lot of functions are blocked...

There is another way to Change Window and Copy/Paste?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem:

.vbs has a lot of bugs in the blocked computer.

`Ctrl + C` or `V` works better as lower case: `"^{c}"` & `"^{v}"`

And the `% + something` doesn't work in any way.

So worked like this way for me:

> ```
> Dim WS
> set WS = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
>
> WS.AppActivate "Protocolos - Internet Explorer" ' name of the sheet
> CScript.Sleep 100
> WS.SendKeys "^{c}"
>
> CScript.Quit
> ```